# How to Develop a FIDO2 Authenticator Android App

Tags: android, webauthn, fido

I'm planning to develop a my own FIDO2 authenticator android app instead of what Google PM provides(Simillar to IDmelon). For example when webauthm.io website is visited and clicked on register the browser generates a QR Code. My app should scan the QR Code and use CTAP to communicate with browser and complete FIDO2 registration and later login.
My question: What are the first steps in developing a FIDO2 authenticator app? Are there any specific SDKs or tools recommended for beginners or I should implement the whole protocol?

Comment: With Android 14 Google has introduced the Credential manager API, designed to be used for Passkey authentication. As Passkey is more or less FIDO2 it might be a good starting point: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/10/simple-and-secure-sign-in-on-android-with-credential-manager-passkeys.html

Comment: But what if I want to work with lower versions of android? Do I need to implement CTAP by myself?

Comment: As far as I know CTAP is only for communication with external FIDO keys. Thus an app can not interact with the browser as a FIDO2 CTAP system. I only see the way to use the Credential manager API and be limited to Android 14+.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a credential provider for Android (e.g. a passkey provider). Apps don't implement CTAP directly, they leverage platform credential management APIs that handle transports for you, including FIDO Cross-Device Authentication.

All documentation is available here: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-provider

Comment: For lower versions of android like 13 what could be done?